# Data rendering issue with PDF conversion library

Tags: php

I'm working on a small functionality that render data retrieved from the database in a chart whereby data are diplayed monthly. Since the users are French speaking people, I'm trying to translate months data in French using the commented code snippet in the following script.

```
<?php

    function getMonths($begin, $end)
    {
        $monthsData = array();

        $dateBegin = new \DateTime($begin);
        $dateEnd = new \DateTime($end);

        while ($dateBegin->getTimestamp() < $dateEnd->getTimestamp()) {
            $monthsData[] = $dateBegin->format('F Y');
            $dateBegin->add(new \DateInterval('P1M'));
        }

        return $monthsData;
    }


    $monthsData = getMonths('2018-05-01', '2020-01-01' );


    $percentApporteurData = $_SESSION['reqPourcentageApporteur'];

    $recupapporteur = "select * from apporteuraffaire where id_apporteur ='".$useridapporteur."'";
    $execrecupapporteur = mysql_query($recupapporteur);
    $apporteur = mysql_fetch_assoc($execrecupapporteur);



    $recupcodepromo = "select * from codepromo where codepromo ='".$apporteur['codeapporteur']."'";
    $execrecupcodepromo = mysql_query($recupcodepromo);
    $codepromo = mysql_fetch_assoc($execrecupcodepromo);



  $listeventes = "select * from reporting_formulaire2 where codepromo ='".$codepromo['idcodepromo']."' and codepromo <> 0 and numeroattestation<>'' and statusachat>9 and statusachat<>15 and statusachat<>14 and statusachat<19 ORDER BY  `idformulaire2` DESC ";    
            $exelisteaffaire = mysql_query($listeventes);
            $nombreaffaire =  mysql_num_rows($exelisteaffaire);
            $rf2Data = mysql_fetch_assoc($exelisteaffaire);

            $_SESSION['rf2Data'] = $rf2Data;

?>

<?php
if ($nombreaffaire > 0) {
?>


<?php 
    $listeville="SELECT * FROM  `villedumaroc` where idville='".$apporteur['villeapporteur']."' ";
    $exelisteville=  mysql_query($listeville);
    $resultatville=mysql_fetch_assoc($exelisteville);
?>

<?php

$reqClients = "select DATE_FORMAT(datemodificationstatus, '%M %Y') AS datemodif, SUM(prixpack) AS montant_du_mois  
from reporting_formulaire2 where codepromo ='".$codepromo['idcodepromo']."' and codepromo <> 0 and numeroattestation<>'' 
and statusachat>9 and statusachat<>15 and statusachat<>14 and statusachat<19 
group by datemodif
ORDER BY  `idformulaire2` DESC";
$execReqClient = mysql_query($reqClients);

$grid = array();
while ($client = mysql_fetch_assoc($execReqClient) ) {
    $grid[$client['datemodif']] = number_format(($client['montant_du_mois'] * $percentApporteurData['pourcentage_valeur']/100), 2,',',' ');
}

}

?>

<div class="col-sm-offset-2">
    <center>
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Mois</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Gains (Dhs)</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Fiche comptable du mois</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
        foreach ($grid as $key => $value) {

        /*$yearMonths = array(
            "January" => "Janvier",
            "February" => "Février",
            "March" => "Mars",
            "April" => "Avril",
            "May" => "Mai",
            "June" => "Juin",
            "July" => "Juillet",
            "August" => "Août",
            "September" => "Septembre",
            "October" => "Octobre",
            "November" => "Novembre",
            "December" => "Décembre",
        );

        $key = explode(' ',$key);
        foreach ($yearMonths as $k => $v) {
            //$k = explode(' ', $k);
            if ($key[0] == $k) {
                $key = $v.' '.$key[1];
            }
        }*/




            ?>

                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $key; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $value; ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <?php  ob_start(); ?> 
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-12">
                            <table width='700px' colspan='1' rowspan='1'>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <center>
                                            <br>
                                            <img src="img/logo-helvetica-by-sanad.png">
                                        </center>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>  
                            </table>
                            <br><br><br>

                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-12">

                        <table width='700px' colspan='1' rowspan='1'>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <center> 
                                        <br> 
                                        <b><u>AFFAIRES DU MOIS (<?php echo $key; ?>)</b></u> 
                                    </center>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>    
                        <br><br>
                        <table style="border-style:solid; border-width:1px;background-color: grey;margin-top: 3px;margin-bottom: 3px;" border=1 width='700px' colspan='1' rowspan='1'>
                            <tr style="background-color: #fff;height: 40px;">
                                <td  align='left' style="height: 40px;width: 33%;padding: 0px 5px 5px 5px;">

                                    <center>   
                                        <table style="background-color: grey;width: 240px;height: 20px;">
                                            <tr><td style="text-align: center;"><p style="color: #fff;margin-bottom: 0px;"><b>Apporteur d&apos;affaires</b></p></td></tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </center>
                                    <br>
                                    <table style="width: 100%;border-color: gray;border-left: 0px;border-right: 0px;border-top: 0px;border-bottom: 0px;margin-top: 3px;" border="2"  cellpadding=2 cellspacing=2>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="width: 20%;">Nom et pr&eacute;nom</td>
                                            <td style="background-color: #ebebeb;width: 40%;">&nbsp;<?php echo $apporteur['nomapporteur']." ".$apporteur['prenomapporteur']; ?></td>
                                            <td style="width: 20%;" >&nbsp;E-mail</td>
                                            <td style="background-color: #ebebeb;width: 20%">&nbsp;<?php echo $apporteur['emailapporteur'];?></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="width: 20%;">T&eacute;l&eacute;phone</td>
                                            <td style="background-color: #ebebeb;width: 40%;">&nbsp;<?php echo $apporteur['telephoneapporteur'];?></td>
                                            <td style="width: 20%;" >&nbsp;Ville</td>
                                            <td style="background-color: #ebebeb;width: 20%">&nbsp;<?php echo $resultatville['nomville'];?></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>    
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        </div>
                        <br><br>

                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-12">

                        <table style="border-style:solid;border-color: grey; border-width:1px;background-color: grey;margin-top: 3px;margin-bottom: 3px;" border=1 width='700px' colspan='1' rowspan='1'>
                            <br><br>
                            <tr style="background-color: #fff;">
                                <td colspan="5">
                                    <center>
                                        <table style="background-color: grey; width: 240px;height: 20px;margin-top: 3px;margin-bottom: 3px;">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="text-align: center;">

                                                    <p style="color: #fff;margin-bottom: 0px;"><b>Commissions</b></p>

                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </center>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <br><br>
                            <tr style="background-color: #d6d6d6;font-weight: 700;">
                                <td>&nbsp;Client</td>
                                <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;Pack&nbsp;</td> 
                                <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;Prix du pack&nbsp;</td>
                                <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;Pourcentage&nbsp;</td>
                                <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;Commission&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>    

                            <?php
                            $listeventes = "select nom, prenom, nomprenom, pack, prixpack, DATE_FORMAT(datemodificationstatus, '%M %Y') AS datemodifstatut  from reporting_formulaire2 where codepromo ='".$codepromo['idcodepromo']."' and codepromo <> 0 and numeroattestation<>'' and statusachat>9 and statusachat<>15 and statusachat<>14 and statusachat<19 ORDER BY  `idformulaire2` DESC ";    
            $exelisteaffaire = mysql_query($listeventes);
            $nombreaffaire =  mysql_num_rows($exelisteaffaire);
            //$rf2Data = mysql_fetch_assoc($exelisteaffaire);
                                $afrs = array();
                                $array = array();

                                    while ($ref = mysql_fetch_assoc($exelisteaffaire)) {
                                        $mois = $ref['datemodifstatut']; 
                                            $array[$mois] = array();
                                            $array[$mois][$ref['nomprenom']] = array();
                                            $array[$mois][$ref['nomprenom']]['nomprenom'] = $ref['nomprenom'] ;
                                        $array[$mois][$ref['nomprenom']]['pack'] = $ref['pack'];
                                        $array[$mois][$ref['nomprenom']]['prixpack'] = $ref['prixpack'];
                                        $array['pourcentage'] = $percentApporteurData['pourcentage_valeur'];
                                    }



                                    foreach ($array as $index => $val) {

                                        if ($index == $key) {

                                            foreach ($array[$key] as $n => $arr){


                            ?>
                            <tr style="background-color: #fff;">
                                <td><b>&nbsp;<?php echo $arr['nomprenom']; ?></b></td>
                                <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;<?php echo $arr['pack']; ?></td>
                                <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;<?php echo $arr['prixpack']; ?></td>
                                <td style="text-align: right;padding-right: 4px;">
                                    <?php 
                                        if (isset($percentApporteurData['pourcentage_valeur']) && is_numeric($percentApporteurData['pourcentage_valeur'])) {
                                            echo $percentApporteurData['pourcentage_valeur'];
                                        } else {
                                            echo "0";
                                        }
                                    ?>
                                </td>
                                <td style="text-align: right;padding-right: 4px;">
                                    <?php

                                        $percentage = 0;
                                        if (isset($percentApporteurData['pourcentage_valeur']) && is_numeric($percentApporteurData['pourcentage_valeur'])) {
                                            $percentage = $percentApporteurData['pourcentage_valeur'];
                                        }
                                        echo number_format(($arr['prixpack'] * $percentage / 100), 2,',',' ');
                                        $afr = $arr['prixpack'] * $percentage / 100;
                                        $afrs[] = $afr;
                                    ?>
                                </td>

                            </tr>
                            <?php

                                $totalAfrs = 0;
                                for ($i = 0; $i < count($afrs); $i++) { 
                                    $totalAfrs += $afrs[$i];

                                }

                                $array[$mois]['total'] = $totalAfrs;
                            ?>                         

                            <tr style="background-color: #fff;height: 20px;"><td colspan="5" height='40'></td></tr>                  

                            <tr style="background-color: #fff;">
                                <td colspan="4" style="text-align: right;"><b>Total&nbsp;</b></td>

                                <td style="background-color: #d6d6d6;text-align: right;padding-right: 4px;"> &nbsp;
                                    <?php
                                        echo number_format($totalAfrs,2,',',' ');  
                                    ?>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div>    
                        <p style="font-size: 12px;text-align: left;">  
                            <br><br><br><br>
                            Ce montant total de vos commissions <span style="font-weight: bold;">(<?php echo number_format($totalAfrs,2,',',' '); ?> Dhs)</span> vous sera vers&eacute; sur votre compte bancaire n&deg; <?php echo $apporteur['ribcomplet'];?>
                        </p>
                        <p style="font-size: 12px;text-align: left;">  
                            <br><br><br><br>
                            Fait &agrave; Casablanca, le <?php echo date('d/m/Y');?>
                        </p>
                        <br><br>
                    </div>                            

                    <?php $monthContent = ob_get_clean(); ?>   
                    <?php 

                        require_once( 'pdf/MPDF57/mpdf.php'); // Include mdpf
                        $stylesheet = file_get_contents('pdf/pdf.css'); // Get css content
                        $html = '<div id="pdf-content">
                                    Your PDF Content goes here (Text/HTML)
                                </div>';
                        // Setup PDF
                        //$mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8', 'A4-L'); // New PDF object with encoding & page size
                        $mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8', 'A4'); // New PDF object with encoding & page size
                        $mpdf->setAutoTopMargin = 'stretch'; // Set pdf top margin to stretch to avoid content overlapping
                        $mpdf->setAutoBottomMargin = 'stretch'; // Set pdf bottom margin to stretch to avoid content overlapping
                        // PDF header content
                        $mpdf->SetHTMLHeader('<div class="pdf-header">

                                              </div>'); 
                        // PDF footer content                      
                        $mpdf->SetHTMLFooter('<div class="pdf-footer">

                                              </div>'); 

                        $mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1); // Writing style to pdf
                        $content = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
                        $mpdf->WriteHTML($monthContent); // Writing html to pdf
                        //$mpdf->Output('lubus_mdpf_demo6.pdf','D'); // For Download

                        //$nomfichierserveur="pdf/save/apporteuraffaire/comptabilite/test.pdf";
                        $fichierPDF = "pdf/save/apporteuraffaire/comptabilite/".str_replace(' ','',$key)."_".$apporteur['nomapporteur']."-".$apporteur['prenomapporteur']."_Fiche-Comptable.pdf";

                        $mpdf->Output($fichierPDF, 'F');//enregistrer sur serveur

                    ?> 

                        <a href="<?php echo $fichierPDF; ?>" class="list-group-item">
                            <img width="10%" height="10%" src="img/logopdf.png" />
                        </a>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php

            }
                                        }
                                    }

        }
    ?>
</table>
    </center>
</div>
```

My script above is rendering this view:
[image]

Whenever I uncomment the commented code snippet so I can translate months names in French, I'm having this output:

[image]

The output that you see above is the content of PDF files.
Any suggestions?

P.S: this how the commented code snippet is working when tested separately:

```
<?php
$grid = array(
    "February 2018" => 498.90,
    "June 2018" => 1000,
    "May 2018" => 500.00,
    "April 2018" => 300.90,
    "March 2018" => 250.50,
);



$yearMonths = array(
    "January" => "Janvier",
    "February" => "Février",
    "March" => "Mars",
    "April" => "Avril",
    "May" => "Mai",
    "June" => "Juin",
    "July" => "Juillet",
    "August" => "Août",
    "September" => "Septembre",
    "October" => "Octobre",
    "November" => "Novembre",
    "December" => "Décembre",
    );

 $keys = array();   
foreach ($grid as $key => $value) {
    $key = explode(' ',$key);

    foreach ($yearMonths as $k => $v) {
        //$k = explode(' ', $k);
        if ($key[0] == $k) {
            $keys[] = $v.' '.$key[1];
        }
    }
}  

var_dump($keys);

array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(13) "Février 2018"
  [1]=>
  string(9) "Juin 2018"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "Mai 2018"
  [3]=>
  string(10) "Avril 2018"
  [4]=>
  string(9) "Mars 2018"
}
```

Comment: Doesn't look like that loop will ever do anything. So `$key` is an array now... Why don't you `var_dump` that stuff and see what's different?

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv Which loop are you referring to? If you are talking about the foreach that processes $yearMonths, it does do the job, that is, translating months names. I tested the commented code snippet on https://3v4l.org, it worked fine. And without that commented code my initial script is working properly.

Comment: I do not have access to the input data like you do. My initial impression was that it does nothing. My bad. But still, `$key` is obviously messed up after that piece of code runs. Pretty hard for anyone to say why if we don't see any input data.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv check out my latest update you will find that var_dump() output.

Comment: So `$keys` is what you'd expect. Means the bug is somewhere else, probably some loop left open and closed in an unexpected place. Try to clean up all that HTML output and go through the whole flow. Or better yet install xdebug and go through it step by step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was coming from the foreach loops below while loop. After making sure that only while loop is used, everything works like a charm. Here is my new code that is working fine:

```
<?php

    function getMonths($begin, $end)
    {
        $monthsData = array();

        $dateBegin = new \DateTime($begin);
        $dateEnd = new \DateTime($end);

        while ($dateBegin->getTimestamp() < $dateEnd->getTimestamp()) {
            $monthsData[] = $dateBegin->format('F Y');
            $dateBegin->add(new \DateInterval('P1M'));
        }

        return $monthsData;
    }


    $monthsData = getMonths('2018-05-01', '2020-01-01' );


    $percentApporteurData = $_SESSION['reqPourcentageApporteur'];

    $recupapporteur = "select * from apporteuraffaire where id_apporteur ='".$useridapporteur."'";
    $execrecupapporteur = mysql_query($recupapporteur);
    $apporteur = mysql_fetch_assoc($execrecupapporteur);



    $recupcodepromo = "select * from codepromo where codepromo ='".$apporteur['codeapporteur']."'";
    $execrecupcodepromo = mysql_query($recupcodepromo);
    $codepromo = mysql_fetch_assoc($execrecupcodepromo);



  $listeventes = "select * from reporting_formulaire2 where codepromo ='".$codepromo['idcodepromo']."' and codepromo <> 0 and statusachat>7 and statusachat<>15 and statusachat<>14 and statusachat<19 ORDER BY  `idformulaire2` DESC ";    
            $exelisteaffaire = mysql_query($listeventes);
            $nombreaffaire =  mysql_num_rows($exelisteaffaire);
            $rf2Data = mysql_fetch_assoc($exelisteaffaire);

            $_SESSION['rf2Data'] = $rf2Data;

?>

<?php
if ($nombreaffaire > 0) {
?>


<?php 
    $listeville="SELECT * FROM  `villedumaroc` where idville='".$apporteur['villeapporteur']."' ";
    $exelisteville=  mysql_query($listeville);
    $resultatville=mysql_fetch_assoc($exelisteville);
?>

<?php

$reqClients = "select DATE_FORMAT(datemodificationstatus, '%M %Y') AS datemodif, SUM(prixpack) AS montant_du_mois  
from reporting_formulaire2 where codepromo ='".$codepromo['idcodepromo']."' and codepromo <> 0  
and statusachat>7 and statusachat<>15 and statusachat<>14 and statusachat<19 
group by datemodif
ORDER BY  `idformulaire2` DESC";
$execReqClient = mysql_query($reqClients);

$grid = array();
while ($client = mysql_fetch_assoc($execReqClient) ) {
    $grid[$client['datemodif']] = number_format(($client['montant_du_mois'] * $percentApporteurData['pourcentage_valeur']/100), 2,',',' ');
}

}

?>

<div class="col-sm-offset-2">
    <center>
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Mois</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Gains (Dhs)</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Fiche comptable du mois</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
        foreach ($grid as $key => $value) {
            $yearMonths = array(
            "January" => "Janvier",
            "February" => "Février",
            "March" => "Mars",
            "April" => "Avril",
            "May" => "Mai",
            "June" => "Juin",
            "July" => "Juillet",
            "August" => "Août",
            "September" => "Septembre",
            "October" => "Octobre",
            "November" => "Novembre",
            "December" => "Décembre",
        );

        $key2 = explode(' ',$key);
        foreach ($yearMonths as $k => $v) {
            //$k = explode(' ', $k);
            if ($key2[0] == $k) {
                $key2 = $v.' '.$key2[1];
            }
        }
            ?>

                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $key2; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $value; ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <?php  ob_start(); ?> 
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-12">
                            <table width='700px' colspan='1' rowspan='1'>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <center>
                                            <br>
                                            <img src="img/logo-helvetica-by-sanad.png">
                                        </center>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>  
                            </table>
                            <br><br><br>

                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-12">

                        <table width='700px' colspan='1' rowspan='1'>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <center> 
                                        <br> 
                                        <b><u>AFFAIRES DU MOIS (<?php echo $key; ?>)</b></u> 
                                    </center>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>    
                        <br><br>
                        <table style="border-style:solid; border-width:1px;background-color: grey;margin-top: 3px;margin-bottom: 3px;" border=1 width='700px' colspan='1' rowspan='1'>
                            <tr style="background-color: #fff;height: 40px;">
                                <td  align='left' style="height: 40px;width: 33%;padding: 0px 5px 5px 5px;">

                                    <center>   
                                        <table style="background-color: grey;width: 240px;height: 20px;">
                                            <tr><td style="text-align: center;"><p style="color: #fff;margin-bottom: 0px;"><b>Apporteur d&apos;affaires</b></p></td></tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </center>
                                    <br>
                                    <table style="width: 100%;border-color: gray;border-left: 0px;border-right: 0px;border-top: 0px;border-bottom: 0px;margin-top: 3px;" border="2"  cellpadding=2 cellspacing=2>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="width: 20%;">Nom et pr&eacute;nom</td>
                                            <td style="background-color: #ebebeb;width: 40%;">&nbsp;<?php echo $apporteur['nomapporteur']." ".$apporteur['prenomapporteur']; ?></td>
                                            <td style="width: 20%;" >&nbsp;E-mail</td>
                                            <td style="background-color: #ebebeb;width: 20%">&nbsp;<?php echo $apporteur['emailapporteur'];?></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="width: 20%;">T&eacute;l&eacute;phone</td>
                                            <td style="background-color: #ebebeb;width: 40%;">&nbsp;<?php echo $apporteur['telephoneapporteur'];?></td>
                                            <td style="width: 20%;" >&nbsp;Ville</td>
                                            <td style="background-color: #ebebeb;width: 20%">&nbsp;<?php echo $resultatville['nomville'];?></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>    
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        </div>
                        <br><br>

                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-12">

                        <table style="border-style:solid;border-color: grey; border-width:1px;background-color: grey;margin-top: 3px;margin-bottom: 3px;" border=1 width='700px' colspan='1' rowspan='1'>
                            <br><br>
                            <tr style="background-color: #fff;">
                                <td colspan="5">
                                    <center>
                                        <table style="background-color: grey; width: 240px;height: 20px;margin-top: 3px;margin-bottom: 3px;">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="text-align: center;">

                                                    <p style="color: #fff;margin-bottom: 0px;"><b>Commissions</b></p>

                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </center>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <br><br>
                            <tr style="background-color: #d6d6d6;font-weight: 700;">
                                <td>&nbsp;Client</td>
                                <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;Pack&nbsp;</td> 
                                <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;Prix du pack&nbsp;</td>
                                <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;Pourcentage&nbsp;</td>
                                <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;Commission&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>    

                            <?php
                            $listeventes = "select nom, prenom, nomprenom, pack, prixpack, DATE_FORMAT(datemodificationstatus, '%M %Y') AS datemodifstatut  from reporting_formulaire2 where DATE_FORMAT(datemodificationstatus, '%M %Y') = '". $key ."' and codepromo ='".$codepromo['idcodepromo']."' and codepromo <> 0 and statusachat>7 and statusachat<>15 and statusachat<>14 and statusachat<19 ORDER BY  `idformulaire2` DESC ";    
                            $exelisteaffaire = mysql_query($listeventes);
                            $nombreaffaire =  mysql_num_rows($exelisteaffaire);
                            //$rf2Data = mysql_fetch_assoc($exelisteaffaire);
                                $afrs = array();
                                $array = array();

                                    while ($ref = mysql_fetch_assoc($exelisteaffaire)) {

                            ?>
                            <tr style="background-color: #fff;">
                                <td><b>&nbsp;<?php echo $ref['nomprenom']; ?></b></td>
                                <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;<?php echo $ref['pack']; ?></td>
                                <td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;<?php echo $ref['prixpack']; ?></td>
                                <td style="text-align: right;padding-right: 4px;">
                                    <?php 
                                        if (isset($percentApporteurData['pourcentage_valeur']) && is_numeric($percentApporteurData['pourcentage_valeur'])) {
                                            echo $percentApporteurData['pourcentage_valeur'];
                                        } else {
                                            echo "0";
                                        }
                                    ?>
                                </td>
                                <td style="text-align: right;padding-right: 4px;">
                                    <?php

                                        $percentage = 0;
                                        if (isset($percentApporteurData['pourcentage_valeur']) && is_numeric($percentApporteurData['pourcentage_valeur'])) {
                                            $percentage = $percentApporteurData['pourcentage_valeur'];
                                        }
                                        echo number_format(($ref['prixpack'] * $percentage / 100), 2,',',' ');
                                        $afr = $ref['prixpack'] * $percentage / 100;
                                        $afrs[] = $afr;
                                    ?>
                                </td>

                            </tr>
                            <?php
                                 }               


                                $totalAfrs = 0;

                                for ($i = 0; $i < count($afrs); $i++) { 
                                    $totalAfrs += $afrs[$i];

                                }

                                $array[$mois]['total'] = $totalAfrs;
                            ?>                         

                            <tr style="background-color: #fff;height: 20px;"><td colspan="5" height='40'></td></tr>                  

                            <tr style="background-color: #fff;">
                                <td colspan="4" style="text-align: right;"><b>Total&nbsp;</b></td>

                                <td style="background-color: #d6d6d6;text-align: right;padding-right: 4px;"> &nbsp;
                                    <?php
                                        echo number_format($totalAfrs,2,',',' ');  
                                    ?>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div>    
                        <p style="font-size: 12px;text-align: left;">  
                            <br><br><br><br>
                            Ce montant total de vos commissions <span style="font-weight: bold;">(<?php echo number_format($totalAfrs,2,',',' '); ?> Dhs)</span> vous sera vers&eacute; sur votre compte bancaire n&deg; <?php echo $apporteur['ribcomplet'];?>
                        </p>
                        <p style="font-size: 12px;text-align: left;">  
                            <br><br><br><br>
                            Fait &agrave; Casablanca, le <?php echo date('d/m/Y');?>
                        </p>
                        <br><br>
                    </div>                            

                    <?php $monthContent = ob_get_clean(); ?>   
                    <?php 

                        require_once( 'pdf/MPDF57/mpdf.php'); // Include mdpf
                        $stylesheet = file_get_contents('pdf/pdf.css'); // Get css content
                        $html = '<div id="pdf-content">
                                    Your PDF Content goes here (Text/HTML)
                                </div>';
                        // Setup PDF
                        //$mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8', 'A4-L'); // New PDF object with encoding & page size
                        $mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8', 'A4'); // New PDF object with encoding & page size
                        $mpdf->setAutoTopMargin = 'stretch'; // Set pdf top margin to stretch to avoid content overlapping
                        $mpdf->setAutoBottomMargin = 'stretch'; // Set pdf bottom margin to stretch to avoid content overlapping
                        // PDF header content
                        $mpdf->SetHTMLHeader('<div class="pdf-header">

                                              </div>'); 
                        // PDF footer content                      
                        $mpdf->SetHTMLFooter('<div class="pdf-footer">

                                              </div>'); 

                        $mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1); // Writing style to pdf
                        $monthContent = mb_convert_encoding($monthContent, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
                        $mpdf->WriteHTML($monthContent); // Writing html to pdf
                        //$mpdf->Output('lubus_mdpf_demo6.pdf','D'); // For Download

                        //$nomfichierserveur="pdf/save/apporteuraffaire/comptabilite/test.pdf";
                        $fichierPDF = "pdf/save/apporteuraffaire/comptabilite/".str_replace(' ','',$key)."_".$apporteur['nomapporteur']."-".$apporteur['prenomapporteur']."_Fiche-Comptable.pdf";

                        $mpdf->Output($fichierPDF, 'F');//enregistrer sur serveur

                    ?> 

                        <a href="<?php echo $fichierPDF; ?>" class="list-group-item">
                            <img width="10%" height="10%" src="img/logopdf.png" />
                        </a>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php




        }
    ?>
</table>
    </center>
</div>
```